# Search for combination and pattern of strings

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

Need help on a part of the bash script and it needs to find a particular pattern string. A sample string is given below:

```
//*-----------
//* %%SET %%ABC     = %%BLANK
//* %%SET %%RESTART = %%BLANK7
//* %%SET %%DANGO= 236985
//*-----------
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 123456
//* %%SET %%ABC=   GSG34
//* %%SET %%RESTART = RESTART
//* %%ENDIF
//*-----------
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 463123
//* %%SET %%DANGO= 236985
//* %%ENDIF
//*-----------
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 15641
//* %%SET %%RESTART = %%BLANK7
//* %%ENDIF
//*-----------
```

- I need to find the combination of ODATE,ABC,RESTART within an IF and ENDIF condition
- I specificly need to check beween IF and ENDIF. Also it should check for a condition that the three parameter ODATE,ABC and RESTART exist between the IF and ENDIF. If the condition is satisfied then it should print those.
- I tried the below commands

> cat file | sed -n '/%%IF/,/%%ENDIF/p'

```
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 123456
//* %%SET %%ABC=   GSG34
//* %%SET %%RESTART = RESTART
//* %%ENDIF
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 463123
//* %%SET %%DANGO  = 236985
//* %%ENDIF
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 15641
//* %%SET %%RESTART = %%BLANK7
//* %%ENDIF
```

I only need to find below:

```
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 123456
//* %%SET %%ABC=   GSG34
//* %%SET %%RESTART = RESTART
//* %%ENDIF
```

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/%%IF /{:a;N;/%%ENDIF/!ba;/ODATE/{/ABC/{/RESTART/p;}}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '/%%ODATE EQ 123456/{p=1}/ENDIF/&&p{p=0;print}p' file
```

Output:

```
//* %%IF %%ODATE EQ 123456
//* %%SET %%ABC=   GSG34
//* %%SET %%RESTART = RESTART
//* %%ENDIF
```

Basically `awk` prints a line here when the variable `p` is true. `p` will set to when the line *ODATE EQ 123456* appears and reset on the next *ENDIF*. The *ENDIF* itself will get printed too.

---

Following your comment below, you can use this command:

```
awk '/IF/&&/ABC/&&/RESTART/' RS='\n//\\*---+\n'
```

The key here is the *record separator* `RS`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But Insted of filtering out from the ODATE number can we specificly check beween IF and ENDIF. Also it should check for a condition that the three parameter ODATE,ABC and RESTART exist between the IF and ENDIF.

Comment: You can use the following command `awk '/IF/&&/ABC/&&/RESTART/' RS='//\\*---+\n'`

Comment: Thank you. This did the Magic.

Comment: @ArunKurian PS: I've updated my answer and added the `\n` at the beginning of `RS`. That removes the extra newline.